# Inline editing for static block

Tags: javascript

I have a page with title and content blocks. User must have a feature as inline editing. So he (user) must can click to title text and get inline edittor where he can change text for title and other. Same as for content block. 
Question :
 Which of existing RICH editors can help me? I need simple functionality, feature for  manually add css (I mean I can set default css style or he(editor) must automatically getting current style), feature for setting button which will be available for user for editing, automatically get a height of content, must have feature for return plain text and must be easy in settings and setup.

Please advise . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many 'lightweight' rich text editors, but I always came back to [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

It is open source, feature rich and can be customized to your needs (by reducing features, adding languages and a lot more).
It also has a nice plugin API which makes it really easy to extend.